# Plotting x/y coordinates onto an image in R -- points distorted

Tags: r, ggplot2

Essentially, I have an R script that takes X/Y coordinate info from a .csv, and plots them over a picture of a hand. The resolution of the picture is always 1280x1024. The coordinates are plotted successfully, and look to be in the right shape, but are distorted in that they are not overlaid on the hand 'to scale', if that makes sense (pic attached for reference, plus code).

I am very much a beginner when it comes to R -- this is part of a project for my master's -- and so any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

```
## Data
dbCoords <- read.csv("dbCoords.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",") ## Load coordinate .csv
xCoords <- as.integer(dbCoords$x) ## Assign x-values
yCoords <- as.integer(dbCoords$y * -1) ## Assign y-values (make negative)
image <- read.bitmap("s1_Blank_Img.jpg")
rImage <- rasterGrob(image, width=unit(33.866666667,"cm"), height=unit(27.093333333,"cm")) ## Load image, set it to 1280x1024 in cm

#Graph
ggplot(dbCoords, aes(xCoords,yCoords)) + 
  annotation_custom(rImage) +
  geom_point(colour="red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(min(xCoords),max(xCoords))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), lim=c(min(yCoords),max(yCoords))) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(aspect.ratio = nrow(image)/ncol(image))
```

[image: RStudio plot output]

dput output for dbCoords.csv:

```
structure(list(x = c(711L, 826L, 426L, 791L, 624L, 577L, 573L, 
404L, 921L, 814L, 917L, 903L, 728L, 722L, 905L, 601L, 587L, 705L, 
415L, 721L, 588L, 902L, 733L, 795L, 716L, 803L, 915L, 845L, 404L, 
573L, 588L, 909L, 904L, 652L, 623L, 771L, 580L, 595L, 782L, 641L, 
402L, 779L, 810L, 917L, 893L, 905L, 592L, 418L, 616L, 824L, 915L, 
730L, 724L, 703L, 624L, 726L, 883L, 729L, 628L, 442L, 820L, 890L, 
803L, 708L, 799L, 794L, 580L, 914L, 903L, 585L, 419L, 591L, 590L, 
802L, 687L, 783L, 917L, 421L, 900L, 773L, 601L, 902L, 889L, 571L, 
791L, 620L, 726L, 422L, 821L, 617L, 816L, 822L, 768L, 404L, 917L, 
895L, 808L, 585L, 630L, 737L, 729L, 621L, 786L, 586L, 421L, 895L, 
891L, 598L), y = c(143L, 736L, 513L, 132L, 435L, 157L, 723L, 
440L, 318L, 298L, 401L, 535L, 317L, 340L, 218L, 80L, 326L, 220L, 
521L, 131L, 219L, 543L, 239L, 123L, 201L, 260L, 279L, 740L, 433L, 
700L, 161L, 227L, 392L, 428L, 88L, 293L, 336L, 737L, 320L, 392L, 
440L, 318L, 117L, 324L, 548L, 451L, 167L, 506L, 93L, 724L, 221L, 
273L, 134L, 171L, 82L, 205L, 554L, 121L, 415L, 472L, 701L, 307L, 
122L, 158L, 205L, 316L, 679L, 361L, 223L, 167L, 534L, 286L, 163L, 
728L, 166L, 238L, 313L, 518L, 566L, 346L, 343L, 430L, 235L, 704L, 
138L, 97L, 156L, 462L, 267L, 423L, 342L, 684L, 306L, 431L, 300L, 
203L, 116L, 179L, 408L, 274L, 100L, 95L, 235L, 230L, 522L, 440L, 
599L, 645L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -108L))
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Just added the output for dput, @Quinten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all you are trying to do then I would probably avoid `ggplot`. Base R (here I've also used to the `png` library to load my image) gives you everything you need and it isn't any harder.

Here I'm loading the R logo and then plotting points corresponding to a square at 0,0 which is 100 pixels wide and 100 pixels high.  Throughout I make sure the point coordinates are translated to 0,1 on each axis. You can see the plot always has the correct aspect ratio and I can control the point locations relative to the points on the plot.

There may be an even neater way with the `imager` library

```
image1 <- png::readPNG("Rlogo.png")
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), ann=F,axes=F,asp=dim(image1)[1]/dim(image1)[2])
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
rasterImage(image1,0,0,1,1)
points(x=c(0,0,100,100)/dim(image1)[2],
       y=c(0,100,0,100)/dim(image1)[1],pch=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, @George Savva. I've just tried to put this into my current code, but having trouble figuring out the exact way to modify the 'points' argument to fit in my points.

`xCoords` contains the x values, and `yCoords` contains the y values (y values have been made negative). I have thus tried, `points(x=c(xCoords)/dim(handImage)[2])` and `points(y=c(yCoords)/dim(handImage)[1])`, but to no avail. I have tried to better understand this function but I've been struggling -- would be appreciated if you could lend a hand!

Comment: did you try `points(x=xCoords/dim(handImage)[2], y=yCoords/dim(handImage)[1])`

Comment: you need both x and y coordinates in a single call to points